# How removing behaviors attached to the scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I remove special instructions which are executed only at the scroll event ?

For example I got this code :

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
// instructions
});
```

And I want that "instructions" are functional ONLY when one of my div is displayed (display:block).
Actually, when I hide the div, I don't want anymore that the instructions are applyed when scrolling...

I could make a function which gether my instructions and enable them to be executed thanks to a simple "if(mySpecialVar==true){//instructions}". Like this :

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
if(mySpecialVar==true){//instructions}
});
```

This way, I could modify mySpecialVar when I hide or display the div. But I don't even want the browser makes this simple condition when instructions have not to be executed (for max optimization).

Any idea please ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the function in a variable, bind it to the event and later remove it like this:

```
var the_function = function(){/*instructions*/};
```

In the code where you show the div:

```
$(document).on("scroll", the_function);//Attach the event
```

In the code where you hide the div:

```
$(document).off("scroll", the_function);//Remove the event
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much :) I saw these methods but I misunderstood how it works. Now it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($(your_div).is(":visible")){//instructions}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named function and jQuery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)/[.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods. No point in binding to an event you don't want:

```
// Bind
$(document).on("scroll", myScroll);
// Unbind
$(document).off("scroll", myScroll);

function myScroll() {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Same answer than the first one, so same feedback : thank you ! That's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:visible`:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($("#mySpecialDiv").is(":visible")){
        //instructions
    }
});
```

Documentation:
[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Demo: (hide the div and scroll, nothing will happen, show div and scroll, you'll get a popup)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJrEj/)